# Error in Swipe Gesture Recognizer during navigating from one page to other

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

When I am clicking on  my back button more than 3 times it throws error while it works better on first click. I have used SWIPE GESTURE RECOGNIZER on  first page and dragged that to second page and vice versa, but buttons stop to work after multiple click. The error is as follows.

```
2014-05-26 11:07:07.319 Prototype[946:11303] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 'Push segues can only be used when the source controller is managed by an instance of UINavigationController.'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1c8c012 0x10c9e7e 0x466e71 0x458ad9 0x458b54 0x10dd705 0x14920 0x148b8 0xd5671 0xd5bcf 0xd4d38 0x4433f 0x44552 0x223aa 0x13cf8 0x1be7df9 0x1be7ad0 0x1c01bf5 0x1c01962 0x1c32bb6 0x1c31f44 0x1c31e1b 0x1be67e3 0x1be6668 0x1165c 0x201d 0x1f45)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using a push without a navigationbar.  Are you trying to push a uitableview controller directly?  That produces the same error.

Comment: so what should i do eliminate that error, i m not getting the point should i use other option that push but why